# Iframe scrolls to middle of the page on load in Firefox

Tags: iframe

I have a website www.negovista.com with an iframe on the middle of the page. In Firefox the page scrolls to the middle of the page when I load the page. Any way to avoid this? Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

I can see there is `onload` event written in your iframe to scroll to `(0,0)`. I think if you can change the `onload` function to `return false;` or remove that `onload="top.scrollTo(0,0)"` from iframe may help. Please try.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the suggestions. I tried both of them and they didn’t work unfortunately. I therefore decided to delete the iframe. Thx Flemming

Comment: Ah! sorry, bad luck. You are welcome.